# require_once works on windows but not linux

Tags: php, windows, linux

On my windows XP system, `require_once('/stuff.php');` works fine, but on the linux server it says file not found until i change it to `require_once('stuff.php');`  Is there some setting I can change to make this work on linux?

Comment: you should use **proper** path to a file. `'/stuff.php'` is improper one for sure. Get yourself a book on computer basics and learn what path is

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel I'm too busy programming to learn about computers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is "stuff.php" in the same directory as the file doing the include/require?

If so, then `require_once('stuff.php')` should work on both systems. Otherwise, other answers here will probably be of more help.

For reference: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

Answer (score 3):

You probably want:

```
require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'stuff.php');
```

`dirname(__FILE__)` will return the current directory, then you append the OS specific separator and the filename.

Answer (score 1):

Using `/file` on linux will make it look in the root folder (compare with `C:\`), try using `./stuff.php`.

Answer (score -1):

Antoher idea is to use $root variable , where you store root of project ( "/" for windows and "" for linx )

Answer (score -1):

Use PHP's DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR constant for slashes.

like

```
$path . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'file.php'
```